# Java has-a relationship

Tags: java, inheritance, relationship

Would the below be correct for the following statement. "A man has a best friend who is a dog."

```
public class Mann {
     private BestFriend dog;
     //etc
}
```

Comment: Without context such questions lead to nowhere. In your example every man has a best friend, and exactly one. The name is dog for all men best friends - so that is far from reasonable. `All man have one dog, which is of type BestFriend` would be my translation of that code. Switch at least BestFriend and dog.

Comment: Simply calling `BestFriend` a dog doesn't necessarily make it so. `BestFriend` could easily be implemented to have methods like `quack()` and no matter what you call it, `dog` or `cat`, it can `quack()`. It'd be more suitable to create a concrete class `Dog` or a more abstract one using interfaces that could allow you to define what kind of `BestFriend` this `Mann` has via the constructor or a set function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Dog should by type, because man can have other "type of best friend":

```
public class Mann {
     private Dog bestFriend;
     //etc
}
```

**Update**

Most close to real-live implementation will look like:

```
public interface Friend {}

public class Man implements Friend {}

public class Dog implements Friend {}

public class FriendRelationship {
    private Friend first;
    private Friend second;

    public FriendRelationship(Friend first, Friend second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}

Man aPerson = new Man();
Dog aBog = new Dog();
FriendRelationship bestFriends = new FriendRelationship(aPerson, aDog);
```

This way one can express friend relationships between any entities. Common base class is not required. You only need implement `Friend` interface.

Comment: @userunknown Man should have a an array of friends with a bestFriend pointer to a certain friend

Answer (score 5):

I'd say it would be more correct to write:

```
public class Man extends Entity {
     private Entity bestFriend = new Dog(); // Where Dog extends Entity
     //etc
}
```

Why? Let's say you have a bunch of different entities, say `Man`, `Cat`, and `Dog`. It would then make sense to have them each extend an `Entity` class, that specifies various attributes every entity should have. Each one, then, could have a `bestFriend` attribute, that could be any other `Entity`.

However, as pointed out in the comments, it would be even more correct to allow for specifying a `bestFriend` in the constructor:

```
public class Man extends Entity {
    private Entity bestFriend;

    public Main(Entity bestFriend) {
        this.bestFriend = bestFriend;
    }
    //etc
}

...

Dog bobDog = new Dog();
Man bob = new Man(bobDog);
```

Comment: I am not sure all `Dog`s are `Friend`s

Comment: If the `bestFriend` was passed in via a constructor or mutator on `Man`, then I think this would be a better example.  I agree with @krock, the current implementation means all instances of `Man` will have a `bestFriend` that is a `Dog`

Comment: @JasonBraucht True, I was thinking that but excluded a constructor for brevity.

Comment: I'm not sure that `Entity` is the best name for the root of this inheritance hierarchy.  Maybe `Animal` or `Mammal` would work, or even `LivingOrganism`.  But `Entity` is so generic as to be meaningless.  Objects should represent the same things that nouns represent, and pretty much anything that can be represented by a noun is an entity.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin I get where you're coming from and mostly agree, however "trust" and "hope" are not entities :P

Answer (score 1):

One extra 'n' in man, otherwise it seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Man extends world.life.animalia.chordata.mammalia.primates.hominidae.hominini.homo.Homo_sapiens {
    private world.life.animalia.chordata.mammalia.carnivora.canidae.canis.c_lupus.CanisLupusFamiliaris dog = new world.life.animalia.chordata.mammalia.carnivora.canidae.canis.c_lupus.CanisLupusFamiliaris();
    private concept.population.social.Friend bestFriend = dog;
}
```

this way bestFriend is a pointer (or reference) to the dog.

Comment: @duffymo We discover faster-than-light, we fly to the edge of the universe, we pass outside the known universe... `[segmentation fault] [core dumped]` :)